# XML document parsing javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, html

```
 <container xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container" version="1.0">
    <rootfiles>
    <rootfile full-path="OPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml"/>
    </rootfiles>
    </container>
```

How can i access it using Javascript?
I need to get "full-path" value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml='';
var oParser = new DOMParser();
var oDOM = oParser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
console.log(oDOM.querySelector('rootfile').getAttribute('full-path'));
```

Comment: i am loading the sml using httprequest

Comment: Maybe you got a DOM element directly from your request, then, you should try :
var domXml = answerData;
console.log(domXml.querySelector('rootfile').getAttribute('full-path'));